# How to make light of lighthouse?

Tags: node-editor, light, edit-mode

I tried to do it with volume scatter but result was ugly and strange. Today I found the solution: I make mesh and add emission shader to volume but after sompositing this light disappears. I want try to make animation with rotating light.
Is there any way to make cool light?
[image]

[image]

My blend file 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_-tV3odolwlaC14SG9WVzUyRlk

Comment: There was a very good example of a lighthouse beam at Blender Cloud, sadly its video only but heres the link https://cloud.blender.org/p/caminandes-3/56c6da5cc379cf0079716873

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The light is being lost at the point where you multiply in the Ambient Occlusion as that pass doesn't include the 'light' since it's purely emissive. One solution would be to activate the Emission pass in the Render Layer properties and then Add it in as shown (Emit connected to an Add Color node) :

[image: Add Emit]